# Need help understanding fourier series.

Tags: fourier-series

Im reading about fourier series, I have the solutions manual for a problem. But i dont understand it

The problem is

$ U(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{0≤t<1} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{1≤t<2}
\end{cases}$  $ U(t) = U(t+n*2)$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n737S.png

The period is 2, so we have the lower limit 0 and upper limit 2. Why do the upper limits change?

Comment: Do you understand what happens in the first line (for $a_0$)? It's exactly the same in the other two lines (for $a_n$ and $b_n$), it's just not written out.

Comment: No. I really dont understand it. I understand $\frac2T$ and the limits of integration from 0 to T but not more than that.

Comment: OK, what about $\int_0^2 u(t) \, dt = \int_0^1 u(t) \, dt + \int_1^2 u(t) \, dt$ then? That's a basic property of integrals.

Comment: No, I didn't know about this property. This is the first time I see it. But Iooking at it ,I understand how this property works now.

Comment: Well, that's a bit strange, since you should have come across that *long* before getting to Fourier series...

Comment: Anyway, once you have that identity, you just substitute the values for your function $u(t)$ on the respective intervals.

Comment: I honestly have never seen it before. But I think I maybe got it. $$\int_0^T u(t)\,dt= \int_0^2 u(t)\,dt= \int_0^1 u(t)\,dt + \int_1^2 u(t)\,dt$$

We have 
$ U(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{0≤t<1} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{1≤t<2}
\end{cases}$

$\text{since u(t) = 1 in the interval between 0 and 1. We get the integral } \\[2ex]

$$\int_0^1 1\,dt$

$\text{since u(t) = 0 in the interval between 1 and 2. We get the integral } \\[2ex]

$$\int_1^2 0\,dt$

Is this correct?

Comment: Right, that's it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it. I was really stuck

Comment: One thing Im not completely sure about is why the limits of integration for a and   b are also 0,1

Comment: See my very first comment above.

Comment: I see it now. $$\int_0^1 1*cos(nwt) \,dt + \int_1^2 0*cos(nwt) \,dt = \int_0^1 cos(nwt) \,dt $$